# Maximum-weight independent set problem for a path graph

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-theory

While taking the [Algorithms: Design and Analysis II](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/course-v1:Engineering+Algorithms2+SelfPaced/about) class, one of the questions asks about the maximum-weight independent set problem for a path graph. shown below is a (blurry) screenshot of the problem statement, and the corresponding lecture videos are on YouTube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0awkct8SkxA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLOkbHGRsv0

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Im_zjFkZDCY
[image]

This problem can be elegantly solved by dynamic programming, with literally one line of code.

```
a[i] = max(a[i - 1], a[i - 2] + w[i])
```

The question is as follows:

> Which of the following is true for our dynamic programming algorithm
>   for computing a maximum-weight independent set of a path graph?
>   (Assume there are no ties.)
>
> - As long as the input graph has at least two vertices, the algorithm never selects the minimum-weight vertex.
> - The algorithm always selects the maximum-weight vertex.
> - If a vertex is excluded from the optimal solution of two consecutive subproblems, then it is excluded from the optimal solutions of all
>     bigger subproblems.
> - If a vertex is excluded from the optimal solution of a subproblem, then it is excluded from the optimal solutions of all bigger
>     subproblems.

Turns out, the correct answer is #3, which is somewhat intuitive, since the optimal solution to a subproblem depends only on the solutions of the previous two subproblems. But it's not clear to me why options 1 and 2 are incorrect. Since the algorithm looks at all the vertices, it seems both of those options should be correct too.

Comment: What would the equation/solution be if the problem were to be modified to find the max IS in a cycle C with n vertices v1. . . vn (for every i < n, vi is connected to vi + 1, vn is connected to v1 and these are the only edges in C).

Comment: @RedApple Ask a new question, don't hijack this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
the algorithm never selects the minimum-weight vertex.
```

Consider: **3-100-4-1-5-100-6
it makes sense to choose 1, the minimum, since we want to choose the two 100's

```
The algorithm always selects the maximum-weight vertex.
```

Consider: **5-99-100-99-7**

It makes sense to exclude the maximum in favour of the to 99's

For both these examples, try see what the algorithm would do and why it works.

A good way of reasoning about these types of problems is to try all permutations of (0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,99,99,99,100,100,100) and it should give you most of the posibilities.

Comment: Your counter examples have ties, which is not allowed by the question. The first three entries of `a` would be `0`, `2`, and `max(2, 0 + 2)` - the last one isn't allowed.

Comment: Once I understood the selection logic better, I was able to come up with my own counterexamples. `10-2-1-4` when min is selected, and `1-3-10-9` when max isn't. I'll accept your answer because it lead me to a better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

OP here: Here's a full answer for completeness sake, inspired by @robert-king's answer.

Consider the path `10-2-1-4`. The vertices selected by the algorithm are `10, 1`, where `1`, the minimum, is selected. Thus, option 1 is incorrect.

Consider the path `1-3-10-9`. The vertices selected by the algorithm are `3, 9`, where the maximum `10` isn't selected. Thus, option 2 is incorrect.

Consider the path `1-9-7-1-5`. The vertices selected by the algorithm are `1, 7, 5`. However, `7` was not included in the optimal solution of the subproblem `1-9-7`. Note that, `7` was not included in the optimal solution of the subproblem `1-9-7-1` either, because the its previous vertex was "heavier", and since all weights are positive, the sum of the next weight and the heavier vertex is certainly greater than `7`. Thus, option 4 is incorrect.

Option 3 is correct. This follows from induction, since the optimal solution to a subproblem depends only on the solutions of the previous two subproblems.